# How to remove activity from stack android for adjust back pressed like web hierarchy?

Tags: android

If i have stack histories of activities like A>B>C>D>E than i need to open C activity and clear all top activities. Than when back pressed I need result in this format C>B>A?

This is not duplicate question.  In this activity we have multiple activity not only 2.

Comment: try this Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in your intent when you are calling activity C

Comment: finish the activities after C whenever you launch new activity from them ?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need an activity to be saved as history (in the stack), then you can put a parameter in the `AndroidManifest.xml` when you declare the activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".ClassName" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

just add the `android:noHistory="true"` to the declaration of the class